# OSGi companion bundle needed?

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, bnd, bndtools

I have two different projects in Eclipse based on Bndtools.
The first produces a JAR with following manifest :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1450251340248
Bundle-Activator: org.osgi.tutorial.MessageCounterActivator3
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: org.osgi.tutorial
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.osgi.tutorial
Bundle-Version: 0.0.0.201512160735
Created-By: 1.8.0_66 (Oracle Corporation)
Import-Package: org.osgi.book.reader.api,org.osgi.framework;version="[1.3,2)",org.osgi.util.tracker;version="[1.4,2)"
Private-Package: org.osgi.tutorial
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
Tool: Bnd-3.0.0.201509101326
```

the second has the following manifest :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1450536025075
Bundle-Activator: org.osgi.book.configadmin.ServerConnectionActivator
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: org.osgi.book.configadmin
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.osgi.book.configadmin
Bundle-Version: 0.0.0.201512191440
Created-By: 1.8.0_66 (Oracle Corporation)
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="[1.3,2)",org.osgi.service.cm;version="[1.3,2)"
Private-Package: org.osgi.book.configadmin;version="1.0.0"
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
Tool: Bnd-3.0.0.201509101326
```

The two projects need the osgi.cmpn : the first for ServiceTracker (package org.osgi.util.tracker) and the second for ManagedService (package org.osgi.service.cm).

The first project works great : I install and start the bundle without problems.
I can install the bundle from the second project but when I start it I receive the following error :

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.osgi.book.configadmin [6]: Unable to resolve 6.0: missing requirement [6.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.cm)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
```

What's the problem ? If both the project need osgi.cmpn JAR ... why the first doesn't throw this error on starting ?

Thanks,
Paolo.

Comment: I solved the error adding the osgi.cmpn as Run requirements in the Run Descriptor of Bndtools (plugin for Eclipse). However I don't understand why it's not required in the first project where the same osgi compendium bundle is used for the ServiceTracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289193/how-to-deploy-osgi-compendium-services-in-karaf-4). Never deploy the compendium jar in OSGi. Instead you need a bundle that implements the spec you depend on.

In your case you need a config admin service impl. There are implementations from felix and from eclipse. Both contain the api.

Comment: You are absolutely right ... I miss the config admin service impl. Now removing the compendium bundle it works great :-)